# Is there anything better than flatpages for Django?

Tags: django, content-management-system, django-flatpages

I was wondering if there's anything better than the flatpages app for Django, because flatpages doesn't even support things like status (draft, published) or publish date. Is there anything out there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[django-cms](http://django-cms.org/) is flatpages on steroids. The development version has turned into an overcomplicated mess, but the current release is excellent.

Comment: Thanks, I played with the demo and it looks pretty good, but I haven't been able to install it on my windows computer (localhost). The instructions don't appear to be for windows, in particular step 4 of what they have here:

http://django-cms.org/installation/

If you know about any tutorial that has instructions for getting this up on localhost on Windows, I'd appreciate it. 

Thanks!

Comment: On windows, you could probably just copy cms/media to your media admin folder as cms. For example, if your media directory is c:\fooproject\media, you need to make the path to your cms specific media c:\fooproject\media\admin\cms

Comment: Thanks for that tip, vezult. I still haven't gotten it going though. I'm getting a lot of errors that make it impossible to add a page. Right now at http://localhost:8000/admin/cms/page/add/, I'm getting:

TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/cms/page/add/
Invalid block tag: 'include_admin_script'

When I Googled that it looks like that's a pre 1.0 tag, so I'm guessing the stable version of Django CMS (rc41) is not for Django 1.x

Comment: So what are you recommending as the 'current release'? The website doesn't explain too well.

Comment: The problem with django-cms is that the project seems to have abandoned releases. They've changed the site such that now they just have links to V1 svn, and the V2 development branch on github.

Answer (score 6):

I would qualify the answer from hasen j.  I've had a lot of luck extending the flatpages app itself.  Check out these sources and then just add the fields you need and update the views.  Not difficult.

http://overtag.dk/wordpress/2008/07/tip-extending-django-flatpages/

http://mrlauer.wordpress.com/2008/05/31/a-little-django-flatpage-trick/

Comment: hehe, man, just rolling your own is easier and more efficient than trying to hack the existing one.

Comment: Depends on how familiar you are with the Django development model.  Johnathan sounds like he's where I was a few weeks ago.  Modifying an existing app will get you much further in much less time.

Comment: I should've said also depends on how much time you have.  Learning django while rolling your own mini-cms doesn't sound very deadline-friendly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've copied out flatpages using the instructions in the link you posted, and will try modifying it to do what I need. It should be a good exercise even if I go with django-cms or django-page-cms.

Comment: I don't know Marco, but if one is using Django, I'd assume they want to learn it and play around with making simple stuff with it. You can't get simpler than this; this is in no way a complete cms.

Answer (score 4):

Just roll your own.

Should be rather simple, really!

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a one-to-one mapping with the flatpage model? I've never done that myself, but I guess it should work.